# What benefits does SharePoint offer over Notes/Domino?

Tags: lotus-notes

I was not sure where I should ask this question but this seemed like a right place. So here it goes.

I have been working on Notes/Domino for over 5 years now. There was a lot of chatter, which I heard the moment I started working on Notes/Domino, that all organizations on Notes/Domino are moving to SharePoint. This chatter has grown louder for past 5 years and now I am moving to SharePoint.

It has been just month learning SharePoint. Now that I have become *vaguely* familiar with SharePoint I am finding it bit hard to digest the fact that SharePoint is beating Notes/Domino.

Let’s start off with installation requirements SharePoint. The list is quite long (at least compared to what is required for [Domino 9](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/prodguid/v1r0/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=1351622732112&osPlatform=Windows)).

For SharePoint 2013 there are [11 prerequisites](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx#section4) before we install Microsoft SQL Server, Windows Server (*not sure if the those 11 prerequisites are included in this*), IIS, Microsoft Visual Studio, Microsoft SharePoint Server, SharePoint Designer, InfoPath (if this list is incorrect/incomplete then do tell me). I don't mean to trash Microsoft or SharePoint but I installed Visual Studio Express at my home on Windows 8 and it installed quite a few other things before it began actual installation.

In Notes/Domino we could simply download Domino Designer (for free) from IBM and start out with development. Without server it would have limited capabilities but it would have everything a developer would require. And it would run on Windows Vista as well without any prerequisites!

The other thing that puzzled me was when I heard the **migration for SharePoint from 2007 to 2010 to 2013**. I worked in Notes/Domino from v7 to v8.5 and we were only required to upgrade to new servers and our applications would run as is (there were some rare exceptions). But we *never* migrated our data. But this doesn't seem to be the case with SharePoint which involves both code and content migration.

So why are organizations preferring SharePoint over Notes/Domino? What are some benefits that SharePoint offers over Notes/Domino?

Comment: Bit of a subjective question, there are hundreds of reasons to choose one platform over another. Welcome to SharePoint.

Comment: @PaulLeigh: Agreed, but this was the best place I could find to ask this question :)

Comment: -Removed the triple version tag. We prefer to use such tags only when the question is specific to a SharePoint version (the solution may not work on another version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having come from a strictly domino environment one of the things that is heads and tails above the domino world is the amount of resources and documentation that are out there. Communities such as this one feature active user groups, and countless blogs have either tried to do something you are trying to accomplish or can at least point you in the right direction.

In addition to the standard views and lists that domino has you can utilize [Business Connectivity Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee661740.aspx) to connect to other data sources from your Sharepoint Environment. The use of [Powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/jj672838.aspx) makes automation of large tasks and scheduled tasks a breeze. As a developer I have found that I don't have to do nearly as many "work arounds" or "hacks" to achieve common tasks. While domino made strides with the release of its xpages framework, it simply doesn't compare to that of the development environment of Microsoft. In addition, you can download and install Sharepoint Foundation on a local machine to play with/ test/ develop with all for free. Microsoft also offers a [Sharepoint SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557253%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Not to mention that since it is a Microsoft Product, it works well with the existing suite of MS Office applications and Active Directory that most companies already use.

I do admit however, it has been a year or two since I have used domino so a lot could have changed. I do remember however that designer was free as a ploy to encourage new developers to use domino and a larger battle for their market share, or so I was told.

Comment: Documentation, yes this is something that IBM was extremely poor at. Especially with XPages which was supposed to stop the onslaught of SharePoint. Here Microsoft wins by a mile! Regarding Sharepoint Foundation, would it install on Windows 8.1? The prerequisites for that state that you require Windows server.

Comment: I have it on win 7. Can't speak for 8. There are set up scripts that will help with getting your environment set up. Google sharepoint development environment and determine which set up suits you best. Good luck...